# How to open file with special characters in the name

Tags: php

In PHP, how can I open a file that has special characters in the name?

The name is similar to iPad|-5542fa5501f31.log

Per another forum, I've tried:

```
$logid = str_replace(" ", "\x20", $_GET['logid']);
$logid = str_replace("|", "\x7C", $logid);
```

To massage the name, but that doesn't work for me either.

I've also already tried:

```
$dst_file = escapeshellarg($dst_file);
```

And of course started out with just straight:

```
$logid = $_GET['logid'];
```

The initial file was created by a PHP script on a Linux system. I'm confused why a PHP script can write a file name like that, but can't open it for reading.

Here's my current code:

```
$logid = str_replace(" ", "\x20", $_GET['logid']);
$logid = str_replace("|", "\x7C", $logid);
$logdate = str_replace("-", "/", $_GET['date'])."/";
$dst_file = $uploads_dir.$logdate.$logid.'.log';

// read the data from the log file
echo "<pre>\n";
if (file_exists($dst_file)) {
    $file_handle = fopen($dst_file, "r");
    while (!feof($file_handle)) {
        $line = fgets($file_handle);
        if (strlen($line) < 3) continue;
        echo $line;
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
} else {
    echo $dst_file." does not exist\n";
}
echo "</pre>\n";
```

Comment: How do you even have a file with a pipe in the filename? What OS is this?

Comment: there is no special symbols in your file name, do not replace anything, just use as is. don't be mistaken with URL encoding (this is what you're trying to do), you don't need it for local file system. if you later will use command line to read file with | you probably will need to escape it like `\|` or use quotes around, like `vi "a|b.txt"`

Comment: @developerwjk: probably *nix, though the person who thought using a pipe in a filename was a good idea should be shot.

Comment: @developerwjk at least for Mac and Linux. Try this: `touch x\|x`

Comment: @OP: Try using `\|` (so, in terms of a PHP string, `"\\|"`).

Comment: I'm not sure why you're replacing `" "`, a space character, with `"\x20"`, which is also a space character. Normally you'd use something like [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php).

Comment: @BradChristie using the pipe might be a slight inconvenience, but I find it's a great way to find out if filename escaping is properly employed everywhere. Unless you are manually doing things in your shell, there's no reason why a pipe character should make *any* difference. Unix supports any byte in a filename except `0x00` and `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody on another forum had suggested using popen, so I tried this, and it works:

```
$logid = $_GET['logid'];
$logdate = str_replace("-", "/", $_GET['date'])."/";
$dst_file = escapeshellarg($uploads_dir.$logdate.$logid.'.log');
echo "<pre>\n";
$handle = popen("cat ".$dst_file, 'r');
while(!feof($handle)) {
    $line = fgets($handle);
    if (strlen($line) > 3) {
        echo $line;
    }
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
pclose($handle);
echo "</pre>\n";
```

The exact same code, except using fopen/fclose (no cat) will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I found was to rename the file then open.  The problem is no PHP functions  so I tried system commands. None worked. The `ftp RNTO` command will rename it.  But it would be much better to filter out "special characters" when the file is saved.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling to open the file "2017-09-19_Comisión_Ambiental.jpg", that "ó" was giving me this error :

> file_get_contents ... failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ...

So I used **utf8_decode** on the filename and it worked :

```
$data = file_get_contents( utf8_decode( $filename ) );
```

I know this is an old question, there's even an accepted answer, I just posted it because it might help somebody.